# How to publish downloadable TensorFlow models to Github

Tags: python, azure, tensorflow, github, azure-functions

I recently was able to download and use a spacy machine learning model by using:

```
pip install en_core_web_sm
```

to run locally.

I was also able to successfully publish an Azure function making use of this model by adding

```
http://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.0/en_core_web_sm-2.3.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm==2.3.0
```

to my "requirements.txt" folder.

I am now in the process of building my own Azure function using one of my own Tensorflow models. I have added the model to my Github Repository in tar.gz format for continuity. However, I am unable to download it as a dependency as with the spacy model. I have released it, and am able to download using

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JoshuaStapleton21/ML_tests_azure/v1.0/testtar.tar.gz
```

but this simply downloads it to a file on my local machine. I need to be able to install it as a dependency using pip.

I have tried solutions such as

```
pip install https://github.com/JoshuaStapleton21/ML_tests_azure/releases/download/ADIR_model_test_1/testtar.tar.gz#egg=v1.0
```

and

```
pip install https://github.com/JoshuaStapleton21/ML_tests_azure/releases/download/ADIR_model_test_1/testtar.tar.gz#egg=v1.0==1.0.0
```

but always error out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've simply archived the files into a `tar.gz` file but for them to work as python modules, you will have to [package them](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

You should be able to package them similar to what the spacy-models repo is doing by looking at their [`setup.py`](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/blob/master/template/setup.py).